# How to change the screen timeout settings on Macbook Air M1?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur

I feel that my MacBook air m1 screen turns dark too soon when I am afk so I would like to extend the screen timeout time. How can I do this? I can't find the "energy saver" option in the system preferences like some older answers on this website suggested.

Comment: What is your MB's year and model and which version of macOS do you have on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in System Preferences/Battery then Battery or/and Sector Adapter.